# How different clock signals can be made

Tags: clock, shift-register

I am not a electronics student. While using shift resistor to save data we need to give it a signal such as 1101 which we need to store in it 1101 signal is synchronous to clock pulse 101010. I want to know how those 1101 signals are made in real life. It seems like a hard task since clock pulses are fast. It seems impossible. [Here](https://youtu.be/1zxXZ3qVpBM) is a video about that topic.

In this video she gives a clock pulse each time. But in real life there is no person hiding in circuits to do that; so how is it possible to do?

Comment: Any kind of digital logic can generate those signals, such as discreet logic or a PLC or FPGA.

Comment: Actually there are little persons hiding behind every circuit: those 1101 would originate from someone - they either programmed it, or made something that generated it.

Comment: @Naman: if you want more "involved" answers I suggest putting more effort in the presentation and clarification of your question. -1 for this, I'll remove my downvote if and when it's done.

Comment: lookup 555 timer

Comment: Binder I know it generates 010101 signal but I want special signal example 1101

Comment: @Voltage Spike is there a way to make those signal synchronous to clock book that I read don't answer the question it only explains basics

Comment: @Mister Mystère thanks I edited it

Comment: You can use a binary counter like CD4024 to count the clock pulses. The binary outputs Q1-Q3 can control the inputs A-C of an analog multiplexer like CD4051. So you have 8 switches where you can connect either low or high. At the COM pin you get the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that video, the user is manually providing a high or low signal to the input of the first flip-flop, and is also manually providing a clock pulse after each input "datum" is set. Obviously this works only as fast as the user is able to perform these tasks, to physically make these changes.

While this demonstrates the behaviour of the shift register, at a rate which the viewer can follow on screen, it certainly doesn't represent the rate of changing clock and data signals in any real application you'll find out there, since these signals are not typically produced by a human.

What the video does *not* show is how these clock and data signals would be produced in real life, which is almost always *another* electronic system, not a person moving wires around and pressing buttons. It would provide the data to be "shifted" into the register, and the accompanying clock signal to indicate the readiness of that data, at frequencies anywhere up to billions of data bits and clock pulses each second.

This example shift register is only *half* of a complete system, the *receiving* half. The other half, not shown, is a *transmitter*, which would also consist of a shift register, but instead of taking *in* one bit at a time (serial), and converting it into an output group of simultaneously present high and low outputs (parallel), the transmitter would have simultaneous access to all the data bits it intends to transmit (parallel), and then does the exact opposite of the receiver; *send* data one bit at a time (serial), with a clock signal to tell the receiver when the data is "ready".

In other words, the transmitter is a "parallel-to-serial" converter, and the receiver is a "serial-to-parallel" converter. The speed at which data can be transmitted between the two is limited only by the electronics used to implement them, since there's no human in between controlling the flow of data.

In this video, the role of transmitter was played by a human. In real life the transmitter is usually another shift register. A real life system might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAa6zu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the clock and transmitted serial data are being produced electronically, and data rate (bits per second) is limited only by the electronics.

If the video showed this whole system, with receiver *and* transmitter, with a human manually setting up all the parallel input bits as 1011 (with four switches, for example), and then pressing a start button to initiate transfer at of all four bits as fast as it can (say, 1MHz), then you could still say that the data had to be set up by a human. You could still argue that even though the bits are transmitted at a rate of one million per second, the four  bits still had to be setup by a slow human. So how to overcome that?

My answer is of course, to use another electronic system to store the data to be transmitted, and make that data available on demand to the transmitter. For example, if you've already recorded some digital audio, and that audio data is to be transmitted over a serial link such as shown above, then an electronic system could be conceived that would present data from its memory to the transmitter, (say 8 bits at a time, a byte), wait for the transmitter to finish sending that chunk, and then present the next chunk, wait, and so on. If the transmitter is sending one bit each microsecond (a million bits per second), then you could transmit an entire audio file of 1MB in 8 seconds, because there's no human involved in the system.

Very often, though, the chain of data movement through a system has a human at one end, and that's the speed bottleneck. Take, for instance, a human typing at a keyboard. The keyboard typically uses serial communications, very similar to what we are discussing here. It may well be capable of sending data to the CPU at a rate of one million bits per second, meaning that it can send a full byte (8 bits) of data in less than 10μs, must wait for the human to produce that data in the first place. Even with the person typing at 10 key presses per second, there's nearly 100,000μs between each press where the transmitter is idle, waiting for the next key event!

Ultimately, data can only flow along a path at the rate of its slowest element, and if there's a human involved, it's the human which will be the slowest element. In this video, the human is only able to setup each data bit and activate the clock once per second, or so. We are capable, though, of building electronic systems that can store and retrieve gigabytes of data, and transmit/receive it at a rate of megabytes or even gigabytes per second, over serial links like this. As long as the producer of data can keep up with the transmitter and receiver, which means as long as all the systems in the chain are electronic, without any humans, then you can setup the data bit, and "clock" it, as fast as the electronics will allow.

To answer the titular question, "how to make a clock", there are a thousand ways to do this electronically, from [555 timers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC) to [crystal oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator), to [phase locked loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) (PLL). Such clocks can be built to oscillate at any frequency you like, up to many gigahertz.

The hardest task isn't building the clock, it is synchronising the presentation of data on the various data lines of the system, with that clock. I reiterate, this is possible to do electronically at whatever data rate the circuitry can support, at ridiculous speeds, but only as long as there's no human in the data path.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your effort is their any specific name to the transmitter that produces serial input signals . Sadly my book only covers half the picture you are  absolute correct .

Comment: @Naman the transmitter might be called "parallel in, serial out, shift register" or something similar. The receiver would be a "serial in, parallel out, shift register"

Comment: @Naman An alternative term for the same general thing would be a "serializer", combined with a "deserializer" for the receiver.